# How to change click event of button

Tags: knockout.js, logical-operators, knockout-mvc

I'm trying to change click event of button. It is possible or not. I want to check button text it text is "Save" then save event call else if text is "Update" then update event call.

Here [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/8/)

**View**

```
 <input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.save ,value: Save" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Save = ko.observable("Save");

    self.save = function () {
        self.Save("Update");  
    }

    self.update = function () {
        alert('click');
        //change button text here       
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using single function for both actions:

```html
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.doAction ,value: Save" />
```

```js
self.doAction = function () {
  if (self.Save() == "Update") {
    self.Save("Save");
  } else if (self.Save() == "Save") {
    self.Save("Update");
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/norbiu/d4kkg/9/

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $root.save(event.target.value) }"
```

then check the parameter in the `save` function for equality to "Save" or "Update".